# Clean blender as fast as possible, or prevent it from accumulating protein powder residue

Tags: cleaning, food, kitchen, appliances

I use a [Ninja Master Prep blender](http://www.ninjakitchen.com/products/0/all/6/ninja-master-prep) to mix protein powder or Soylent with water. Is there a way to clean it very quickly? The blades are super sharp and I'd rather avoid having to scrub bits of powder that get stuck on them.

Ideally, is there something edible to throw in the mix, that would prevent powders from adhering to the blades or the blender in the first place? Some sort of oil perhaps?

Since I use the blender several times a day, I'd rather not run a dishwasher cycle.

Comment: If you have alot of money buy one of these: http://mcd.manitowocfsusa.com/minisite/blended-ice

They have them at McDonalds and it's the fastest way I've ever seen anyone clean a blender.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to clean a blender is to use the blender to clean itself. As you said a dishwasher cycle is pretty time consuming and not optimal if you use the blender several times a day. So turning the blender into a *"dishwasher"* is the solution.

I couldn't think of anything, that would prevent powders from adhering to the blender. But here is the solution if they already are sticking there.

#### What you'll need:

- some hot water (tap water is fine)
- dishwashing liquid
- <sub><sup>(optional)</sup></sub> half a lemon (white vinegar is an alternative)

#### Steps to take:

1. Fill the blender halfway with hot water.
2. Add one or two drops of dishwashing liquid. If you have half a lemon this is the moment to add it. You can chop it coarsely.
3. Turn on the blender and let it run *on Low* for about 30 seconds up to a minute (depending on the power and dirtiness of your blender).
4. Pour out the soapy water.
5. Rinse out the blender thoroughly with more hot water.
6. **Finished!** Place upside down to air dry or use it right away

---

More info (on why a lemon (or vinegar) helps) can be found below.

*Sources:*

- *[wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Clean-a-Blender)*
- *[the kitchn](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-clean-a-blender-in-30-seconds-without-taking-it-apart-first-cleaning-lessons-from-the-kitchn-200776)*
- *[the kitchn](http://www.thekitchn.com/clean-your-blender-tips-from-the-kitchn-199583)*
- *[The Blender Girl](http://healthyblenderrecipes.com/info/cleaning_your_blender)*
- *[WonderHowTo](http://food-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/make-your-dirty-blender-clean-itself-0154425/)*

Comment: This is an excellent and thorough answer. Great work!

Comment: @Mooseman Thank You very much! I appreciate it. :)

Comment: This is exactly what we do with exactly the same model